# AWS Bucket Policy - Athena Results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Looking at access to my Athena results bucket.
Each IAM Role should be dumping their results into an index/folder of their own.
So role1 putting into bucket/role1/  and role2 into bucket/role2.

I have it working for 1 Role, as per below, but ....
They way I have it currently, I would have to add a new statement for every individual IAM Role.
Estimating that there is room for approx. 100 statements before I hit the 20MB limit.

So, wondering if any clever folk out there can see a way of shortcutting this.
Seeing as the last index is the same as the role name - is there a way to parametrize this somehow ? I am happy that any role can dump in the bucket, just so long as the folder matches the rolename.

Grateful for any insight !

```
 Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "sid"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/myRole1"]}
        Action = ["s3:PutObject"]
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/datagroups/myRole1/",
          "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/datagroups/myRole1/*"
        ]
```

Comment: `I am happy that any role can dump in the bucket, just so long as the folder matches the rolename.` - is this a requirement or a compromise?

Comment: Also - can you not do this per user as opposed to per role? I think you mean user...? If so, yes it is possible otherwise there is no IAM policy variable for role name (there is one for username however)...

Comment: Can you tell us more about your situation? Why are you having hundreds of roles accessing Amazon Athena? How are they running queries -- is it via the console or via an API call? How are you specifying the output location for each query (is it via `OutputLocation` on each query)? You might be able to use [IAM Policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to specify the role, but it becomes complex with Role names.

Comment: Roles must put to their own area, as it is sensitive data and so if we give one of them read access, they must only be able to read their own.
There will be users as well, but the majority are roles.
Output location is specified by workgroup.   1 Role = 1 Workgroup = 1 S3 Path.